# NUnit. How to limit the max count of retries for all tests?

Tags: c#, .net, testing, nunit, nunit-3.0

For example:
There 20 tests.
Max retry for each test is 2.
How to stop test run execution if there more than 4 failed tests?

something like /stoponerror for console, but more flexible.
*The /stoponerror option causes execution of the test run to terminate immediately on the first test failure or error.*

I had tried to google and research nunit docs, but can't find any native solution.

Comment: That's not an available feature. You would need to request it of the NUnit team.

Comment: this might be interesting for you they ended with not doing it.
https://github.com/nunit/nunit-console/issues/169

Comment: Why do you want this? If tests fail I would like to know all the test that failed so I can verify that they all work. Unit tests should usually be fast enough that it is not an issue to wait for them. I would also be concerned if you need to use retries, tests that fail randomly indicate an error in either the subject under test or the test itself.

Comment: I have using NUnit for UI testing. I need this option because practice shows (only for my current project) that if test run have more than 5 fails, its related to user/certificate/broken service etc problem and all other test also will be failed. To save company money and do not pass over login procedure(it takes for each test 45-60 sec) better to stop test run. VS test have such option, but in some reason its doesn't work for me; I will dig deeper in this direction.